# How to photocopy from command line?

Tags: printing, hp

I have been controlling my HP printer from Ubuntu command line, I have been able to print and scan, but I would like to photocopy too. Is there any way of achieving that?. I know I could scan and then print the file but I would like a kind of direct way.

Than you everyone

Comment: First scan then print == photocopy!

Comment: I personally don't know much about the matter, but it would probably help if you described your system a bit more and added what version of Ubuntu. what printer model etc you have and how you are currently printing/scanning.

Comment: Doing a photocopy is putting your paper on flatbed or document feeder and then pressing `Copy` button. I don't see advantage of using terminal.

Comment: This ^^^ Reason why I think such feature - computer managed direct scan to print - was never implemented in the drivers in any MFP I know.